# R Script runs very slow on vmware

Tags: r, vmware

We have a test R Script that runs in about 15 seconds on a PC laptop and the same on a 9 year old Mac. On several vmware servers running Windows 2012 R2 the exact same test takes between 1 and 15 seconds to 2 minutes depending on the server. So to remove as many variables as possible we created a VM with Windows 2012 R2, 16GB RAM, 8 cores and nothing else on it except R (no SQL etc.) and the script takes 1 minute and 40 seconds to run.

We did the exact test on each machine. The test script reads a CSV file off the desktop, then performs a Monte Carlo simulation and then writes out a CSV to the desktop. No network reads/writes etc. Everything is contained on the machine.

Has anyone else seen this?  The VM we stood up that has nothing on it but R should scream, it has 8 cores the laptop only has 2, the VM has 16 GB RAM whereas the laptop only has 8 GB

Thoughts?

UPDATE this sample code takes about 14 seconds to run on my laptop (2 cores, 12 GB of RAM) and 1 minute and 3 seconds (4 times slower) on a VMWare server with 8 cores and 16 GB of RAM and nothing else running on the server

Note I am not asking how to optimize the code, but instead, why it runs slower on the VM

```
# parameters
simulations <- 50000 # number of simulations
perimeter <- 1

# randomly generate a point and check if it is in circle
f_point_in_circle <- function(perimeter=1){
  x <- runif(n=1, min=-perimeter, max=perimeter)
  y <- runif(n=1, min=-perimeter, max=perimeter)
  return(list(x=x, 
              y=y,
              in_circle=x^2 + y^2 <= perimeter^2))
}

# Monte Carlo simulations
set.seed(123)
pi_df <- data.frame(x=rep(NA, simulations),
                    y=rep(NA, simulations),
                    in_circle=rep(NA, simulations))
for (i in seq(simulations)){
  my_simulation <- f_point_in_circle()
  pi_df$in_circle[i] <- my_simulation$in_circle
  pi_df$x[i] <- my_simulation$x
  pi_df$y[i] <- my_simulation$y
}

my_pi <- 4 * sum(pi_df$in_circle) / nrow(pi_df)
```

(code from https://blog.alookanalytics.com/2017/04/26/monte-carlo-method-in-r/)

UPDATE

We ran the exact original test on a Hyper V VM and it runs as fast as the physical machines. So it appears to be something with VMWare ?????

Comment: No details `bout the code. How are we supposed to proceed? This seems really a question : "How to do performance profiling in R"? (That might fall under "close as overly broad", but I voted to close as having no code.)

Comment: I didn't include code for two reasons, 1. since the code runs fast on physical machines and slow on VM's it isn't the code itself that is causing the issue. Unless there are certain R libraries that run slow on VM's. 2. The code is proprietary and I can not post it (I can provide a list of libraries used if that would help)

Comment: I've added sample code, but note I am not asking to optimize the code, but to explain why the code takes 4 times as long to run on a vmware server that is significantly more powerful